# how to traverse through a binary tree of characters and convert them to strings in scheme

Tags: scheme

[I provided a picture, I have no idea how to start this or what to do.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bnjkf.png)
I must take a binary tree of characters and make a list of all the possible words that can be created and converted to a string.

write a SCHEME function, named (traverse T), which traverses such a binary tree and returns a list of all of the words that can be constructed by following a path from the root node to a leaf node in the tree. For example, applying your function to the tree in Figure 1 should produce the following list:
("case" "cast" "care" "cart" "crow" "croc" "crab" "cram")

Answer (score 0):

Not a solution, but some hints:

Don't convert from lists to strings too soon, concentrate on building lists of characters.
Convert those lists into strings as a "post-processing" step.
(Related: don't start with writing a function that does everything at once. Ask yourself "is there any part of this that I already know how to do?")

Suppose that you had a node that contains a character, a list of all the character lists created from its left subtree, and a list of all character lists from its right subtree.
How would you create the list that contains everything from the subtree lists, but with the character from "this" node at the front?

That is, if you had the tree

```
 a
/ \
n  t
```

and from the subtrees created `'((#\n))` and `'((#\t))`, how would you produce `'((#\a #\n) (#\a #\t))`?

Then think about the base case; what does an empty tree produce?

Then recursively combine your thoughts.

In the next stage, think about how to get from `'((#\a #\n) (#\a #\t))` to `'("an" "at")`.

(You'll probably want to use `map`, `append`, and `cons` in addition to `list->string`.)